# Javascript divs not stacking

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have some div boxes and when you click a link it replaces an existing box rather than stacks a new one below it.
It's probably best to show you rather than explain.

Or at least I would but creating a jsfiddle doesn't replicate what I see on my webpage.
My webpage is intranet so I cannot share.

This is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/GR6pu/

(When trying to post I get asked to accompany a jsfiddle.net link with some code.
Not quite sure what is needed so I'll post this:)

```
var showed = 'com1';
function com(id) {
    if (showed && showed !== id) {
        document.getElementById(showed).style.display = 'none';
    }
    document.getElementById(id).style.display = 'block';
    showed = id;
}
```

What should hopefully happen is:

You start in community box.
When you click 'lam' you get a box below it = 'lam activities'.
If you subsequently click 'dispatch' this 'lam activites' box is replaced with 'dispatch activities'.
This bit works fine on my website with what I have posted in the fiddle.

Then, in 'lam activities' if you click 't45' you should get another box below it, but on my website the 't45' box replaces the 'lam activities' box rather than stacks another below it.

My goal is to have the 't45' box stacked underneath the 'lam activities' box.

From reading other threads on the forum I know you like your posters to detail what they have tried...
My knowledge on all things web based is small.
4 weeks ago I had never created a website and I've managed to teach myself enough HTML and CSS to create a working website but Javascript is still new to me, hence I don't have the knowledge to fiddle about with the js to make it work.
I tried changing none to block but this then creates more boxes than I would like.

Thanks, Kristian

Comment: Your fiddle is not working. Error in the debugger when clicking anything `Uncaught ReferenceError: com is not defined`. Setting the fiddle to `no wrap - in <head>` will fixes that error but you still have an issue when you click `Planning`, error : `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null`. You need to make sure the fiddle you post only includes the relevant parts and that those work. (I'm assuming `Planning` is not needed for this question....?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> When you click 'lam' you get a box below it = 'lam activities'.
>
> Then, in 'lam activities' if you click 't45' you should get another
>   box below it, but on my website the 't45' box replaces the 'lam
>   activities' box rather than stacks another below it.
>
> my goal is to have the 't45' box stacked underneath the 'lam
>   activities' box.

Overall you got 2 issues, the HTML is invalid as closing tags are missing and your code is not correct, hence it will not show the expected elements.

---

#### Fixing your HTML

---

Your demo fiddle is broken in the first place and does not demonstrate the issue you have.

You cannot show `lam1` if the `lam1` element is inside the `com2` element which you are still hiding `display: none`, please inspect your HTML after clicking `t45`:

---

[image]

---

The reason you end up with incorrect nested HTML like that is due to missing closing tags which creates invalid HTML.

All `<a>` tags are missing their matching `</a>` closing tags.

All main `div`tags, such as `<div id="com1"..>`, `<div id="lam1"..>`, etc.. are missing their matching `</div>` closing tags.

Browsers try a **best-guess**, adding closing tags where it seems most appropriate, hence you might end up with unexpected HTML, such as sibling elements becoming nested instead.

***Edit: The `</a>` are not required (my bad), only the 3rd `</div>` was missing in each section. I updated the fiddle and posted code to reflect that***

---

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/D7bh2/) - Adding missing closing tags fixes the demo and now shows the issue you are having.

---

#### Fixing your code

---

Now that the missing closing tags are added fixing the HTML in the fiddle which now works and shows the issue we can fix your code.

Your second function will always hide the `t45` element and then show the task-element, hence it "replaces" it. I'm assuming you want similar functionality whereby the task element is replaced as you click on different "tasks".

In that case you cannot use the `showed` id but need to keep a separate record of the task-id (or what ever you want to call it)

```
function lam(id) {
    // this removes the t45 element you want to keep
    // I'm assuming you want to track clicked lams separately
    if (showed && showed !== id) { 
        document.getElementById(showed).style.display = 'none';
    }

    document.getElementById(id).style.display = 'block';
    showed = id;
}
```

Change that to the following and both elements are visible.:
    var taskId;

```
function lam(id) {
    if (taskId && taskId !== id) {
        document.getElementById(taskId).style.display = 'none';
    }

    document.getElementById(id).style.display = 'block';
    taskId = id;
}
```

---

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/TSX8k/) - Fixing the code.

---

Here is the fixed HTML and code for completeness from the fiddle above.

HTML:

```
<div class='whitebox'>
    <div class='subheader'>community</div>
    <div class='links'> 
        <a onclick="com('com1');"><div class='boxlink'>LAM</div>
        <a onclick="com('com2');"><div class='boxlink'>DISPATCH</div>
        <a onclick="com('com3');"><div class='boxlink'>PLANNING</div>
    </div>
</div> <!-- closing </div> was missing -->

<div id="com1" style="display:none">
    <div class='whitebox'>
        <div class='subheader'>lam activities</div>
        <div class='links'>
            <a onclick="lam('lam1');"><div class='boxlink'>T45</div>
            <a onclick="lam('lam2');"><div class='boxlink'>SYNC</div>
            <a onclick="lam('lam3');"><div class='boxlink'>ESSS</div>
            <a onclick="lam('lam4');"><div class='boxlink'>IND</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div> <!-- closing </div> was missing -->

<div id="com2" style="display:none">
    <div class='whitebox'>
        <div class='subheader'>dispatch activities</div>
        <div class='links'>
            <a onclick="lam('lam2');"><div class='boxlink'>SYNC</div>
            <a onclick="lam('lam3');"><div class='boxlink'>ESSS</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div> <!-- closing </div> was missing -->

<div id="lam1" style="display:none">
    <div class='whitebox'>
        <div class='subheader'>t45 tasks</div>
        <div class='links'> 
            <a onclick="t45('t451');"><div class='boxlink'>REMOVAL</div>
            <a onclick="t45('t452');"><div class='boxlink'>ADJUST</div>
            <a onclick="t45('t453');"><div class='boxlink'>RECEIPT</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div> <!-- closing </div> was missing -->

<div id="lam2" style="display:none">
    <div class='whitebox'>
        <div class='subheader'>sync tasks</div>
        <div class='links'> 
            <a onclick="t45('t451');"><div class='boxlink'>emea</div>
            <a onclick="t45('t452');"><div class='boxlink'>namer</div>
            <a onclick="t45('t453');"><div class='boxlink'>s asia</div>
            <a onclick="t45('t454');"><div class='boxlink'>n asia</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div> <!-- closing </div> was missing -->
```

JavaScript:

var showed = 'com1';
var taskId;

```
function com(id) {
    if (showed && showed !== id) {
        document.getElementById(showed).style.display = 'none';
    }

    document.getElementById(id).style.display = 'block';
    showed = id;
}

function lam(id) {
    if (taskId && taskId !== id) {
        document.getElementById(taskId).style.display = 'none';
    }

    document.getElementById(id).style.display = 'block';
    taskId = id;
}
```

Comment: hi, many thanks for your good input. the original jsfiddle has the closing divs- they are displayed in red font though??
i tested the demo but the issue is still the same, perhaps my explanation was poor. when you click on t45 in lam activities the lam activities box is replaced with t45 tasks, however the desire is to have the t45 box displayed below the lam activities box.

Comment: @user3018362: You also have other issues, such as hiding the tasks again when changing communications types but I think you can figure that out using the ids stored in the `taskId` and the `showed` variables. -- something similar to [**this fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/KLK8g/) might be what you need in the end.

Comment: ah ok i understand now, my apologies i made the assumption the demo was showing the fix- my bad. i guess the fiddle not working but the html working goes back to your comment on browsers trying to fix the issue themselves. even that little bit of information i never knew but i won't forget it! thank you very much for fixing my fiddle AND the main issue, it has saved me.

Comment: @user3018362: I edited my answer as well as you were correct, the `</a>` tags were **not** required, it was only the 3rd `</div>` which was missing in each section causing the elements to be nested. Ones I added them **only** your demo worked again as well. Glad it all worked out in the end.

Answer (score -1):

Lets break this down:

```
if (showed && showed !== id) {
    document.getElementById(showed).style.display='none';
}
```

If `showed` is set and is not equal to the new `id` passed in the function, get the element with the ID of `id` and set it to `display:none;`

```
document.getElementById(id).style.display='block';
```

Get the element with the ID of `id` and set it to `display:block;`

```
showed=id;
```

Set the `showed` variable to be the value of the `id` passed into the function.

So basically, the function hides the previous element and then shows the element that has the ID you passed into the function. If you don't want to hide the previous element, you just need to remove the part of the function that does that (the `if( showed && showed !== id ) { ... }` statement block)

Comment: thank you for your good explanation. i have read it a couple of times but am not yet digesting all of it, perhaps that will come with experience. i experimented with removing the statement block but it did not have the desired effect.